# i am getting a syntax error : return outside function

Tags: python, syntax-error

Using this code:

```
def get_filters():
    """
    Asks user to specify a city, month, and day to analyze.

    Returns:
        (str) city - name of the city to analyze
        (str) month - name of the month to filter by, or "all" to apply no month filter
        (str) day - name of the day of week to filter by, or "all" to apply no day filter
    """
    print('Hello! Let\'s explore some US bikeshare data!')
    # TO DO: get user input for city (chicago, new york city, washington). HINT: Use a while loop to handle invalid inputs
    while True:
     city = input('Which city do you want to explore Chicago, New York or Washington? \n').lower()
     if city in CITIES:
               break

# TO DO: get user input for month (all, january, february, ... , june)
     month = get_user_input('All right! now it\'s time to provide us a month name''or just say \'all\' to apply no month filter. \n(e.g.all,                              january, feburary, march, april, may, june) \n> ',MONTHS)

    # TO DO: get user input for day of week (all, monday, tuesday, ... sunday)
     day = get_user_input('One Last thing. Could you type one of the week day you want to analyse?''You can type \'all\' again to apply no  day                          filter. \n(e.g. all, monday, sunday) \n>',DAYS)

     print('-'*40)
return city, month, day
```

I am getting a syntax error:

```
return outside function
```

Comment: You return it outside of the class, you function should be like this     def function(val1):
        # do stuff
        return ""
    
    but you do this.
    
    def funciton(val1):
        # do stuff
    return ""

Comment: That is because you wrote a `return` statement outside of a function. You have to mind your indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Python blocks works with indents you, and whenever you want to return something from a function, `return` should be at the same indent of the rest of your function body.
Go like this:

```
def get_filters():
    """
    Asks user to specify a city, month, and day to analyze.

    Returns:
        (str) city - name of the city to analyze
        (str) month - name of the month to filter by, or "all" to apply no month filter
        (str) day - name of the day of week to filter by, or "all" to apply no day filter
    """
    print('Hello! Let\'s explore some US bikeshare data!')
    # TO DO: get user input for city (chicago, new york city, washington). HINT: Use a while loop to handle invalid inputs
    while True:
    city = input('Which city do you want to explore Chicago, New York or Washington? \n').lower()
    if city in CITIES:
        break

    # TO DO: get user input for month (all, january, february, ... , june)
    month = get_user_input('All right! now it\'s time to provide us a month name''or just say \'all\' to apply no month filter. \n(e.g.all,                              january, feburary, march, april, may, june) \n> ',MONTHS)

    # TO DO: get user input for day of week (all, monday, tuesday, ... sunday)
    day = get_user_input('One Last thing. Could you type one of the week day you want to analyse?''You can type \'all\' again to apply no  day                          filter. \n(e.g. all, monday, sunday) \n>',DAYS)

    print('-'*40)
    return city, month, day
```